# Spring Data Elasticsearch's ElasticsearchTemplate vs ElasticsearchRestTemplate vs ElasticsearchOperations

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am in reference to Spring Data Elasticsearch's

- **org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate**
- **org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchTemplate**
- **org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations**

It seems they are different APIs that achieve the same goal but I am not sure what the differences are between those three types and more importantly when to use which?

Also, please guide me regarding Elasticsearch's:

- Java High Level REST Client
- Java Low Level REST Client

How these two are different with respect to each other and with respect to above mentioned Spring's classes?`
Which one to use when and what one should do if they want to use Elasticsearch's client in Spring Boot project?

Can someone please provide advice and guidance?

Answer (score -1):

The `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` is an implementation of the `ElasticsearchOperations` interface using the High Level REST Client.

Please check the below article for more details:
https://theprogrammersfirst.blogspot.com/2020/02/spring-elasticsearch-operations.html

Comment: Please summarise the link as web pages can disappear leaving the answer incomplete - in fact, the URL doesn't point to a valid page!